# How to Deserialize a Json Array with C#?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, restsharp, json-deserialization

I use RestSharp to make a Rest API Call.

```
public class GetValues
{
    public string Values{ get; set; }
}

public class JsonObjects
{
    public List<GetValues> Values{ get; set; }
}

RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest("api/tempCatalog/temp1", Method.GET);

restRequest.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
restRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
restRequest.AddHeader("Authorization", token);

IRestResponse restResponse = clientRest.Execute(restRequest );
string Content = restResponse.Content;

JsonObjects.Values= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonObjects>(Content).Values;
```

I have the above code and it works.

But when the JSON Rest Response contains an array it throws an Exception when deserializing.

When the Rest Response is like this , sometimes ,

```
{ "Fields": [ "Value.temp", ] }
```

I get this exception:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Error converting value'
>
> ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to Namespace.GetValues.

When I say sometimes i mean that i use this Deserialize in multiple API calls this in the question was just an example

These are some Json Arrays that I have as Rest response and I want to deserialize them.

```
{
  "Fields": [

    "Temp1.Value",
    "Temp2.Value",
    "Temp3.Value",
    "Temp4.Value"
  ]

}
```

or these??

```
{

  "Errors":
 [
    
{

      "ErrorCode": "Temp Number",
      "Message": "Temp Message",
      "TempName": "Name"
    }

  ],


  "ValueErrors": []

}
```

or these??

```
{
  
"Total": 1,
  
"Categories": [
    
{

      "Id": "tempID",
      "Name": "tempName"
    }

  ]

}
```

Comment: I edited my question , could you help me now??

Comment: Anyone for help??

Comment: One question: are those responses coming from the exactly same url? They have very different structures. We can combine them into a single response but it's g gonna add complexity to your code.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm reading it correctly, you are getting the following JSON string:

```js
{ 
    "Fields": [ 
        "Value.temp", 
    ] 
}
```

The class you're deserializing to must match this structure, and yours, unfortunately, don't.

So `JsonObjects` must look like this:

```cs
public class JsonObjects
{
    public List<string> Fields { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you mean the "string" field?

Comment: If the JSON isn't exactly like the one above, please, reflect it on your question. That way we can show how to better structure your class.

But in general, you should have the exact correspondence between the JSON and the class you're deserializing into.

Comment: Agreed. If there is more than one possible JSON structure then you need more than one C# data structure. Each C# structure must match to one JSON structure. It's logically impossible to expect different types of JSON to fit into a single C# structure. Can you fit a triangle into a square-shaped hole?

Comment: this is not an answer to this ,  I have edited my question in order to help with this issue , thanks